# Matrix how to get the center Point of Bitmap in Matrix

Tags: android, matrix

I am new to android Matrix. I have a problem with getting the center point(X and Y) of the matrix which is rotated, scale and translated. 
Although I am able to get the x and y of the bitmap, I am having problem after I rotate the bitmap using postrotate.

Below is my code to get the X and Y of the bitmap but this will change when rotating the matrix. Any help guys.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    float[] point; 
    float bitmapX = 0; 
    float bitmapY = 0;
    if(targetSelected != null){
        point = new float[] {
                targetSelected.bitmapX, 
                targetSelected.bitmapY + (targetSelected.bitmap.getHeight() * targetSelected.getScaleMatrixFactor())};
        targetSelected.matrix.mapPoints(point);
        bitmapX = point[0];
        bitmapY = point[1];
    }
 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    targetSelected.bX = bitmapX;
    targetSelected.bY = bitmapY;
 }
}


 //The targetSelected Layer
public void rotate90(){
    rotation = rotation + 90;    
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postRotate(rotation, bitmap.getWidth() /2 , bitmap.getHeight() /2 );
    m.postTranslate(bX+(bitmap.getWidth() * getScaleMatrixFactor() / 2),
                    bY-(bitmap.getHeight() * getScaleMatrixFactor() / 2));

    matrix.reset(); // reset old matrix     
    matrix.set(m); // apply new matrix to old matrix

}



/**
 * 
 * @return calculate real scale factor of the matrix.
 */
public float getScaleMatrixFactor(){
    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);
    float scalex = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float skewy = values[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];
    float rScale = (float) Math.sqrt(scalex * scalex + skewy * skewy);
    return rScale;
}
```

Comment: use `Matrix#mapPoints`

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? what is `getScaleMatrixFactor` for? what is your goal?

Comment: I have a Custom ImageView and in it has a layers of bitmap. Each Bitmap has its own matrix. In the main layout. I have a button that will give a 90degree additional for the matrix rotation for the bitmap the user selected. The getScaleMatrixFactor is what I used to get the image width. I just think it to be useful in getting the center of the bitmap. But if not useful I can delete it.  I just having problem when adding rotation to the selected bitmap that has been currently rotated already.

Comment: ok so you know how to rotate the matrix 90 degrees, and what you dont know?

Comment: you can use many `postRotate` calls on the same `Matrix` or you can use Matrix#postConcat`

Comment: I want it to rotate in the center of the Bitmap. For now it look like it rotates not on the center but on the lower edge of the bitmap after it has been transform..

Comment: if you already have matrix m0, create a new matrix m1, postRotate it with 20 degrees for example and the pivot: bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2 and finally m1.postConcat(m0);

Comment: alternatively you can just `mapPoints` on bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2

Comment: Hi Sir @pskink. base on your first suggestion Matrix m = new Matrix(); m.preRotate(rotation, (bitmap.getWidth() * getScaleMatrixFactor())/2 , (bitmap.getHeight() * getScaleMatrixFactor()) /2 );  m.postConcat(matrix);   There is no transformation happening. Is there a problem with this code?. Thanks. I just delete this comment afterwards.

Comment: no transformation happening? what do you mean? what are doing later on with `Matrix m`?

Comment: I have nothing lines added after m.postConcat(matrix) except for invalidating the via. Do I need to matrix.reset();  and  matrix.set(m); sir ?

Comment: then use `m` somewhere, most likely in `setImageMatrix` do you use scale type == MATRIX?

Comment: I added  matrix.set(m); after m.postConcat(matrix); and it works. :). So do I need to include matrix.reset(); before matrix,set(m)?. I don't use Scale Type in the custom view but in the xml I used it.

Comment: no need for `matrix.reset()`

Comment: Wow. I'm really thankful for the time @pskink. You really help me a lot. It took me 3days and I found stackoverflow and a very helpful guy. Thanks Sir :). You can post the answer and I will mark it as answer :)

Comment: or its even better to just call `matrix.preConcat(m)`

Comment: Hi @pskink. I have tried using matrix.preConcat(m). it will disappear my bitmap. I don't know the reason yet. :( so for now I only use postConcat.

Comment: use `matrix.preConcat(m)` but do not `matrix.set(m)`

Comment: Hi @pskink. I have removed m.postConcat(matrix); and matrix.set(m); and just used matrix.preConcat(m); for the new matrix with thre transformation m.preRotate(90, b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight()/2); it works, Thanks.